# Auto Hotkey WinExist does not find open cmd

Tags: autohotkey

I am testing the following piece of code with auto hot key. I want to open a cmd console if one is has not already been opened. Each time i run it a new console is created, ignoring the previous one that have been already opened.

```
#z::Run https://autohotkey.com  ; Win+Z

^!n::  ; Ctrl+Alt+N
if WinExist("Untitled - cmd"){
    WinActivate
    MsgBox GUI "MyGui" already exists.
    }
else{
    Run cmd
    MsgBox GUI "MyGui" does not exist.
    }
return
```

Another question that i have is that when i use the following code, everything works as expected, but when i change untitled - Notepad to untitled - notepad the same thing as in the first excerpt happens, a notepad is created although a previous one is still active. Any advises on why this happen would be really helpful, thank you.

```
#z::Run https://autohotkey.com  ; Win+Z

^!n::  ; Ctrl+Alt+N
if WinExist("Untitled - Notepad"){
    WinActivate
    MsgBox GUI "MyGui" already exists.
    }
else{
    Run Notepad
    MsgBox GUI "MyGui" does not exist.
    }
return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this at the top of your script:

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2
```

[Documentation](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm)

This allows you to use commands like `WinExist` with a partial window name match.